# ImportXML with Google Sheets is not returning the value I would like

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

My goal is to retrieve the "Clôture de la veille" number (90,050 €) from this webpage : https://www.easybourse.com/action-cours/renault/intraday/FR0000131906-25

In Google Sheets, when using the IMPORTXML formula, it returns 0€ instead of 90,050€. Here is my formula: `=value(IMPORTXML("https://www.easybourse.com/action-cours/renault/intraday/FR0000131906-25","//span[@id='cours_dernier_veille']"))`

Can you please explain to me why Google Sheets is returning a wrong value?

Comment: Sure but do you have any idea why the IMPORTXML is blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMPORTXML is only able to read values on the source code of the page but the value you are looking for isn't there, it's added by something that modify the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) (document object model).